How to join two SELECT queries
/* Process 01 */
Select Fld1, Fld2, Fld3, Fld4
From Table01
Where xDate = convert(date, '20240101', 112) as P01

/* Process 02 */
Select Fld1, Fld2, Fld3, Fld4, 1 as Late
From Table01
Where xDate < Convert(date, '20241201', 112) as P02
    
-- Combined Process

In Combine Process, I want to join P01 & P02 queries. How can I join two queries given above?

Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results. We can't tell if you want a vertical join (union) or horizontal join (join)

Btw you don't alias stuff in your where clause - I'm surprised it's works.

Couldn't this just be achieved with <= instead and a CASE expression in the SELECT?

Here are two queries using a UNION or UNION ALL
/* Combine Process */
SELECT Fld1, Fld2, Fld3, Fld4, NULL AS Late
FROM Table01
WHERE xDate = CONVERT(date, '20240101', 112)

UNION ALL

SELECT Fld1, Fld2, Fld3, Fld4, 1 AS Late
FROM Table01
WHERE xDate < CONVERT(date, '20241201', 112);

Please find below the difference between UNION vs UNION ALL:

Use UNION if you want to remove duplicate rows.
Use UNION ALL to include all rows, even if duplicates exist. This typically performs better than UNION so should be used if practical.

Output:



Fld1
Fld2
Fld3
Fld4
Late




1
A
X
P
NULL


2
B
Y
Q
1




Please don't use images. Use table markdown.

@DaleK, update helpful explain difference between Union and Union All

You should point out that UNION ALL is usually much faster and should be prefered unless UNION is really required. Often people don't know that and therefore slow down their query without any need.
